# Did operon evolve after endosymbiosis and specialisation of mitochondria?

Tags: bacteriology, molecular-evolution, mitochondria, eukaryotic-cells, operons

We know that all extant bacteria use the operon system as their mode of regulating gene expression, in contrast to eukaryotes, which use individual gene promoters as well as epigenetic mechanisms, supporting the idea that the first eukaryotes came from archaea as the 'host' in endosymbiosis, not bacteria [2]. However, the endosymbiont bacteria is suspected to be a bacterial phylum, supported by various lines of evidence: in short, an archaea enveloped a bacteria to make a eukarya.

An obscure group of protists was found to have mitochondrial DNA that used operon [1], but other than that, pretty much all eukaryotic cells have mitochondria whose mtDNA does not use operon, instead using similar regulatory mechanisms to eukarya including some basic epigenetics (methylation) [3]. A few operons, mainly for nuclear rRNA genes, have been found in chordates. But clearly it is not the norm.

Based on this, it would seem that operon evolved in prokaryotes some time after the endosymbiosis event, since the two are present mostly exclusively in independent domains of life. But recent research finds that operon seems to be fairly primitive (if I am interpreting [4] and [5] correctly) and could have arisen easily as a de novo insertion sequence, suggesting it would have come about earlier.

Does anyone have any expertise on whether this is the case? Did operon or mitochondria come first?

**References**

[1] Gray MW. Mitochondrial evolution. Cold Spring Harb Perspect Biol. 2012 Sep 1;4(9):a011403. doi: 10.1101/cshperspect.a011403. PMID: 22952398; PMCID: PMC3428767. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3428767/

[2] Gautam Dey, Mukund Thattai, Buzz Baum, On the Archaeal Origins of Eukaryotes and the Challenges of Inferring Phenotype from Genotype, Trends in Cell Biology, Volume 26, Issue 7, 2016,
Pages 476-485, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0962892416300022

[3] Sharma N, Pasala MS, Prakash A. Mitochondrial DNA: Epigenetics and environment. Environ Mol Mutagen. 2019 Oct;60(8):668-682. doi: 10.1002/em.22319. Epub 2019 Aug 6. PMID: 31335990; PMCID: PMC6941438. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6941438/

[4] Yuki Kanai, Saburo Tsuru, Chikara Furusawa, Experimental demonstration of operon formation catalyzed by insertion sequence, Nucleic Acids Research, Volume 50, Issue 3, 22 February 2022, Pages 1673–1686, https://academic.oup.com/nar/article/50/3/1673/6511971

[5] Marco Fondi, Giovanni Emiliani, Renato Fani, Origin and evolution of operons and metabolic pathways, Research in Microbiology, Volume 160, Issue 7, 2009, Pages 502-512, ISSN 0923-2508, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0923250809000539